# How not to show separate browser instance in Unity for Web Apps?

Tags: unity, chromium, webapps, quicklists

I've been working on using the WebApps available in Ubuntu such as Facebook and Reddit. I've been using QLE to add more things to the quicklist to add more functionality to them.

I was going to include screenshots but I can't take a screenshot with the quicklist open.

For example, I went to Facebook and was prompted to integrate so I did. Now I have docked that Facebook "app" and edited the quicklist to include Messages, Photos, and Friends. The command I'm using for each is `chromium-browser --app=(insert link here)`. I run it in "app" mode so that it opens fullscreen just for consistency with the Facebook app.

My problem is that this opens a new Chromium instance on the Unity bar labeled `untitled`. Is there a way to not have that show? I'm hoping to make it look a little more "native" such as the window indicators showing on that Facebook app instead of showing another browser instance.